# Unattend.xml file - Processor Architecture

Tags: windows, windows-10, cpu, xml, computer-architecture

I'm trying to install a Windows 10 image using `Windows Deployment Services`. In the unattend.xml file, processor architecture is defined as below:

```
<component name="Microsoft-Windows-Setup" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" 
language="neutral" versionScope="nonSxS" processorArchitecture="amd64">
```

We are using Dell laptops, arch: **Intel Core-i7 2.6 GHz**

Is `processorArchitecture="amd64"` correct, even though the laptop has an intel chipset?

The unattend.xml does not work currently. Could this be the reason?

Comment: AMD64 is correct for a 64-bit architecture. x86 is for 32-bit architecture. Have a look at this thread too https://serverfault.com/questions/583373/what-is-a-minimal-useful-unattend-xml-file-for-sysprep-on-windows-7

Comment: @spikey_richie not intel64, or x64 ? - Is AMD64 the accepted default?

Comment: All the samples here show AMD64 https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn621892.aspx Might I suggest using the Notepad++ XML Tools Plugin, and performing an XML syntax check? You might have some rogue characters in there.

Comment: @spikey_richie I'll try that. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, AMD64 is correct.

For historical reasons (AMD had a 64-bit architecture ready first that Intel largely copied), the 64-bit version of the x86 chipset is called "AMD64", even for Intel chips.

In the same way way, "x86" does not exactly mean 32-bit. It goes back to the 8086, 80286, 80386, and 80486 family of CPUs. However, it has become synonymous with 32-bit desktop/server CPU architectures.